# Using t() with langcode in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 7 setup with multiple languages (en and fr). In my template files I have a lot of t() texts which im translating using the i10n_client module. This works perfect for translating texts from en to fr IF the t() texts are written in english. However, what if I want to write my t() texts in Danish and being able to translate them to both en and fr? Meaning that the Danish version never will show up as long my Drupal setup only have en and fr as languages.

I tried using the options parameter with the langcode like this:

```
print t('Min tekst', array(), array('langcode' => 'da'));
```

But the translate-text interface (provided by i10n_client module) wont show up when I'm on the en site. Only on the fr site where I can translate it from en to fr.

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string (first parameter) always needs to be in English, from the [Drupal 7 API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7):

> $string A string containing the
>   English string to translate.

The langcode just means that the string will always be translated to Danish, no matter what the active language is. So if you'd be surfing the French site, you'd see the Danish string.

I'm afraid you'll have to translate your Danish strings back to English strings.